# Autoincrement only if certain condition is true

Tags: xml, perl

I'm working on .xml files and I would need an script on perl. I will try to explain on my best. My input has the following format:

```
<p t="opener">
  <w id="23">
    <o>Hi</o>
  </w>
  <w id="24">
    <o>world</o>
  </w>
</p>
```

That is, each word (Hi, world) is delimited by a label (`<o></o>`) and, in addition, it has a correlative number which does not start from 1. This numbering is shown as a value of the attribute "id", inside the label `<w></w>`. Finally, there is a top level (`<p></p>`) which indicate different paragraphs.

The output that I need must have the following format:

```
<p t="opener">
  <w id="1">
    <o>Hi</o>
  </w>
  <w id="2">
    <o>world</o>
  </w>
</p>
```

That is, same format as the input but getting a correlative numbering starting from 1

I guess that the solution has to involve the auto-increment operator (++), but the thing becomes more difficult because I would need to apply the correlative numbering starting from 1 ONLY IF the paragraph has the attribute "opener" (like the input)

In other words, what I need is a condition which print the desired numbering starting from 1 just in case the paragraph be "opener". My suggestion:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$/ = undef
my $numbering = 0;
my $autonumbering = $numbering++;
my $filename      = shift;

open F, $filename or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
while (<F>) {
  if (/<p t=\"opener\".*?<\/p>/s) {
    # If the paragraph is <p t="opener"></p> (the dot (.) stands for every character, including \n)
    s/<w id=\".*?\"/<w id=\"$autonumbering\"/ge # replace the value of "id" by the variable $autonumbering
  }
}
close F;
```

I'm aware that, really, I'm not telling Perl to apply the replacement ONLY in the desired paragraph. I'm telling just to apply the replacement to the whole file if the condition is true, isn't it?

Any suggestion that helps me to apply the restriction and refine my proposal?

Comment: I would suggest not trying to do it all in one line.  Make a `while (my $line=<F>) {` loop and make a state machine.  Restart from the beginning if the condition is found, or make a `@current_paragraph` variable holding the current set of lines from `<p ...>` to `</p>`.  This way you can see what is happening and debug more easily.  Also, if you have such exact text as to make the regexp like `/<p t=\"opener\"...` then you could use the `index` function like `if (index('<p t="opener"', $_) > -1) { ...`

Comment: Are you restricted to perl or are you open to an XSLT solution?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, abiessu. Yes, I'm afraid I'm restricted to perl. But I didn't know that index function. I'm learning about how to use it and trying to apply to my script. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a proper XML parser for this? It'll probably be a lot more work to do it with regexes and conditionals.

Comment: Your Perl code won't even compile. Please have the courtesy to make a reasonable attempt at solving this yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen a good excuse to process XML data without the use of a dedicated XML library.

This program uses [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) and appears to do what you ask for.

In the future please don't give up and seek free help before you have even got your program to compile.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'my.xml');

my $id;

for my $w_element ($doc->findnodes('//p[@t="opener"]/w[@id]')) {
  $w_element->setAttribute('id', ++$id);
}

print $doc->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p t="opener">
  <w id="1">
    <o>Hi</o>
  </w>
  <w id="2">
    <o>world</o>
  </w>
</p>
```